# Adding elements linked list

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, struct, linked-list

I have the following *addEngine function that adds elements to my linked list, which I want to sort in ascending order by year. I must not change the function arguments.

It doesn't work the way I imagine. Why is

```
 a = AddEngine ( a, createEngine ( "TDI 1.9", 2015) );
```

not included when printf in main?

```
      typedef struct TEngine 
    {
        struct TEngine *m_Next;
        int m_Year;
        char m_Type [ TYPE_MAX ];
    } TENGINE;

      typedef struct TArchive
    {
        struct TArchive *m_Next;
        TENGINE *m_Engines;
    } TARCHIVE;

      TARCHIVE *AddEngine  ( TARCHIVE *list, TENGINE *engine )
    {

      TARCHIVE * res = ( TARCHIVE * ) malloc ( sizeof ( *res ) );

      if ( list == NULL )
   {
         res -> m_Next = NULL;
         res -> m_Engines = engine;
         return res;
   }

     int currentYear = list->m_Engines->m_Year;

    // The inserted element is smaller than the first
     if ( currentYear > engine->m_Year )
  {      
         res -> m_Next = list;
         res -> m_Engines = engine;
         return res;
  }

    TARCHIVE *prev = list;
    TARCHIVE *current = list -> m_Next;

    while ( current != NULL )
  {
        currentYear = current->m_Engines->m_Year;

            if ( currentYear >= engine->m_Year )  
       {
               res -> m_Next = prev -> m_Next;
               res -> m_Engines = engine;
               prev -> m_Next = res;

               return list;
       }

      prev = current;
      current = current -> m_Next;
  }

  prev -> m_Next = res;
  res -> m_Engines = engine;
  res -> m_Next = NULL;
  return res;
 }

  return 0;
}
   int main ( void )
 {
      TARCHIVE *a, *b;
      b = a = NULL;
      a = AddEngine ( a, createEngine ( "TDI 1.9", 2015) );
      a = AddEngine ( a, createEngine ( "TDI 1.8", 3001 ) );
      a = AddEngine ( a, createEngine ( "TSI 1.2", 1999 ) );
      a = AddEngine ( a, createEngine ( "TDI 2.0", 2108 ) );
      a = AddEngine ( a, createEngine ( "TDI 1.9", 2005) );
      b = a = AddEngine ( a, createEngine ( "TDI 1.8", 1010 ) );
      a = AddEngine ( a, createEngine ( "TDI 1.9", 2025) );
      a = AddEngine ( a, createEngine ( "TDI 1.8", 2038 ) );

      while ( b )
    {
        printf ("%s", b -> m_Engines -> m_Type);
        b = b -> m_Next;``
    }
```

Comment: 1) Complete the code so that it is compilable. 2) Indent it properly. It's hard to read.

Comment: Make sure that the code is a [mre]

Comment: For last line in function `AddEngine()` you must use `return list;` instead of `return res;` otherwise you might lose list entries. This is the case if you add the second entry `a = AddEngine ( a, createEngine ( "TDI 1.8", 3001 ) );` which will be added behind the first one due to ascending order. But after that you return `res` and thus a pointer to second entry. First list entry gets lost.